# How to convert the following text to comma seperated list using awk - Need to skip headers and trailers

Tags: csv, text, awk

```
+---------------------------------+------------+------+----------+
| Name | NumCourses | Year | Semester |
+---------------------------------+------------+------+----------+
| ABDULHADI, ASHRAF M | 2 | 1990 | 3 |
| ACHANTA, BALA | 2 | 1995 | 3 |
| ACHANTA, BALA | 2 | 1996 | 3 |
+---------------------------------+------------+------+----------+
648 rows in set (0.02 sec)
--------------------------
```

Skip the first 3 lines and the last two lines. I would need an output like -

```
ABDULHADI, ASHRAF M, 2, 1990, 3
ACHANTA, BALA, 2, 1995, 3
ACHANTA, BALA, 2, 1996, 3
```

Comment: Can you not ask whatever process is generating that output to generate a different output for you? Parsing that format is not hard but not needing to do that in the first place is better.

Comment: I am trying to learn awk.. I just wanted to how to create and recreate from one source to another.

Comment: What awk script have you tried so far? How has it not worked?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/awk -f  BEGIN { FS = "," }  # NR > 3  NR > 3 {     # print only the desired fields     printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $5 ,$6 , $7) }

Comment: Update your question with the script so you can format it sanely. Also I'm not sure what you were trying to do with your last question edit but the formatting is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this `awk` and build on it as you need.

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = " *[|] *"              # Set the Field Separator to this pattern
    OFS = ","                   # Set the Output Field Separator to ,
}
NF {                            # Skip blank lines
    $1 = $1                     # Reconstruct your input line
    gsub(/^,|,$/,"")            # Remove leading and trailing ,
    lines[++i] = $0             # Add line to array
}
END {
    for(x=4;x<=i-2;x++)         # Skip first three and last two lines
        print lines[x]          # Print line
}' file
ABDULHADI, ASHRAF M,2,1990,3
ACHANTA, BALA,2,1995,3
ACHANTA, BALA,2,1996,3
```

If your data does not have blank lines then you can remove `NF` and use `NR` as key instead of `++i`

`FS` pattern above is zero or more spaces followed by pipe (placed in character class to consider it literal, since it is a meta character) followed by zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F" *[|] *" 'FNR==NR {a=FNR;next} FNR>3 && FNR<a-2 {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' OFS=", " file{,}
ABDULHADI, ASHRAF M, 2, 1990, 3
ACHANTA, BALA, 2, 1995, 3
ACHANTA, BALA, 2, 1996, 3
```

Read the file two times, one to count the lines, one to get the correct output.
If your `awk` does not work with `file{,}`, change to  `file file` to read it two times